# Java AsyncContext start Runnable

Tags: java, asynchronous, servlets

I've created a Java servlet which does the following:

```
    final AsyncContext aContext = request.startAsync();
        aContext.start(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) aContext.getResponse();
                try {

                    performRequest(proxyRequest, response);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.debug("IO Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage()); 
                } catch (ServletException e) { 
                    jsonResponse.append("ERROR", "Servlet Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
                aContext.complete(); 
                responseWriter.print(jsonResponse);
            }
        });
```

This servlet is called by a front-end UI which performs an AJAX call passing on some huge dataset.
The java servlet runs the method performRequest which can take up to a few minutes (on huge dataset).
I would like the servlet to return fast (the asynch process is triggered right away) otherwise the AJAX promise fails after 30 seconds wait.
What can I do?

Comment: Which part of the code which takes a long time - presumably inside `performRequest`? t's difficult to help if you don't include the code.

Comment: Yeah it's the method performRequest but there's no way to optimize it. I just would like to make sure that once a new thread is started the flow goes back to the client. Instead the client keeps the connection until aContext.complete(). Is there any way to accomplish this?